# How to wrap elements to a new line in a horizontal group in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have a Spark horizontal group (s:HGroup) in Flex with a specified width.
But all labels outside the group are hidden (after the 100 pixels).

```
<s:HGroup width="100">
    <s:Label text="Hello" />
    <s:Label text="Hi" />        
    <s:Label text="Hello" />
    <s:Label text="Hi" />        
    <s:Label text="Hello" />
    <s:Label text="Hi" />      
    <s:Label text="Hello" /> 
    <s:Label text="Hi" />        
    <s:Label text="Hello" />
    <s:Label text="Hi" />        
    <s:Label text="Hello" />
</s:HGroup>
```

*(this is an example, I'm adding elements to the HGroup in Actionscript, not knowing how many)*

So how could I wrap the elements inside a HGroup to a new line when there is an overflow?

Comment: I think this is exactly what you are looking for: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/spark_layouts.html If you look at "Creating a custom Spark layout" section it gives the FlowLayout as an example.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't.  A HGroup lays elements out horizontally.

I think you'll want to use a Group with a [TileLayout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/TileLayout.html)

```
<s:Group width="100">
    <s:layout>
       <s:TileLayout />
    </s:layout>
    <s:Label text="Hello" />
    <s:Label text="Hi" />        
    <s:Label text="Hello" />
    <s:Label text="Hi" />        
    <s:Label text="Hello" />
    <s:Label text="Hi" />      
    <s:Label text="Hello" /> 
    <s:Label text="Hi" />        
    <s:Label text="Hello" />
    <s:Label text="Hi" />        
    <s:Label text="Hello" />
</s:Group>
```

IF the tile layout doesn't work, you'll have to create your own custom layout class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already tried the TileLayout, but it doesn't do what I want when the labels have a variable width.

Comment: Then you'll have to write your own layout.

Comment: Doesn't TileLayout have a variableRowHeight or variableColumnWidth property for that?!

Comment: @J_A_X Nothing defined in the ASDocs... but sometimes w/ Spark; stuff is buried in subclasses so I'm not sure.

Comment: Fairly sure it does, I've used it very recently :)

Comment: @J_A_X I've got this error: **Cannot resolve attribute 'variableColumnWidth' for the component type spark.layouts.TileLayout.**

Comment: There' is a property with a name similar to that.  Use the auto-complete to look for it?

Comment: @J_A_X I'd be curious as to the answer if you could look it up.  As I said; I can't find anything in the ASDocs like this ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/TileLayout.html )

Comment: My Bad, I was using a [3rd party layout](http://www.developria.com/2010/06/variable-width-grid-spark-layo.html).

Answer (score -1):

I've created a solution, probably not the best one, but it works for me.

The point is that I want that someone could click on the labels and executes a function.

Now I have this:

```
<mx:Text id="box" width="100"></mx:Text>
```

In Actionscript:

```
box.htmlText = box.htmlText + "<a href=\"event:hi\">Hi</a>";
box.htmlText = box.htmlText + "<a href=\"event:hello\">Hello</a>";
//etc (actually I've a for loop parsing some XML data)

box.addEventListener(TextEvent.LINK, executeFunction);

private function executeFunction(linkEvent:TextEvent):void {
    Alert.show(linkEvent.text); // will show a alert box with 'hi' or 'hello'
}
```

The text inside the MX textbox stays perfectly within the 100 pixels, as much text as possible at one horizontal line.

Comment: Nothing in your original question had anything to do with clicking on labels.  Why wouldn't this solution work if you were add an explicit height to the Spark labels?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I'm sorry, I forgot to say that :)